# How to sync ionic navigation bar and hardware button in android in a phonegap mobile app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

In my `phonegap` app, there is a ionic navigation bar which has the back button. If we navigate the app using this navigation bar it will navigate properly to each page, but if we use the hardware back button in some point of time, navigation will get messed up. Is there any fixes for this.

```
<ion-view view-title="Store Locator" ng-controller="storelistCtrl" >
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
         <button form="searchId" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios7-search" ng-click="search(searchForm.searchText)"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
        some code here....
    </ion-content>  
</ion-view>
```

This is a page in our app. for the back button i have overrided the actions with `ioPlatform.registerBackButtonAction`

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
       if($state.current.name==="app.home"){

             var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                    title: 'Exit the application',
                    scope: $scope,
                    buttons: [
                      { text: 'Cancel', 
                        onTap: function(e) {
                            $state.go("app.home");
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        text: 'Yes',
                        type: 'button-positive',
                        onTap: function(e) {
                            navigator.app.exitApp();
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  });
        }
        else if($state.current.name==="app.couponlists"){
            $state.go('app.home');
        }
        else if($state.current.name==="app.deallists"){
            $state.go('app.home');
        }
        else if($state.current.name==="app.coupondetail"){
            $state.go('app.couponlists');
        }
        else{
          navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
      }, 100);
```

Comment: please add some code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $ionicPLatform.registerBackButtonAction to do it, redirect according to states, but you need to make sure that $ionicPlatform.ready() is called first, see below code

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
      if ($state.$current.name=="app.login" || $state.$current.name=="app.signup"){
              // Do not go to the previous state (or view) for these states. 
              // Do nothing here to disable H/W back button.
              $cordovaDialogs.alert('Going back is not allowed for this page', 'Notice', 'OK')
              .then(function() {
                // callback success
              });
          }
          else if($state.$current.name=="app.productlist")
          {
            $location.path("/productlist");
          } else {
              // For all other states, the H/W BACK button is enabled
              navigator.app.backHistory();
          }  }, 100);
```

Comment: I tried this one but it is not respecting the $location.path(); to redirect to a specified page.

Comment: when i add      setTimeout(function(){ 
            window.location.href = "#/app/home";
      },0); page is redirecting to the  specified page, but with a flickering effect; because its going to the previous page andd coming back. how can we avoid that?

Comment: Don’t use window.location.href as it will reinitialize the whole app every time it calls. Instead use $state.go("productlist"); in controller  as ionic uses ui-router for routing in angular.js. For reference see this http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: i have tried $state.go("app.home") inside registerBackButtonAction but it is not redirecting to the specified page. Can u help me out in this..

Comment: you need to add a dependency in controller to make it work, please make sure of this that $state or $location is in your controller dependency

Comment: yes i have added $state,$location in my controller dependecies.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the Docs first before implementing. [Ionic Platform Doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

Options available are

1. onHardwareBackButton(callback)
2. offHardwareBackButton(callback)
3. registerBackButtonAction(callback, priority, [actionId])
4. on(type, callback)

make sure your $ionicPlatform.ready() is called first.